# Cannot install Xposed in Yu(Yureka lollipo 5.0.2)

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, xposed-framework, micromax-yu-yureka

While flashing xposed framework via recovery it says that signature verification failed.
It uses 64 bit architecture.
We cannot use xposed installer apk because for lollipop version,manual flashing only supported.
Can anyone resove this?

Comment: Are you using stock recovery? Custom recoveries nowadays (like TWRP) allows disabling signature verification.

Comment: How to disable signature verification in such recoveries?

Comment: You didn't mention (I asked) which recovery? Mostly, it is inside Settings or Advanced.

Comment: I am using twrp?

Comment: I don't have TWRP recovery (device) in my hand right now. Use this [guide](http://www.addictivetips.com/android/what-is-twrp-how-to-install-use-it-on-android-devices-guide/). It says go to **Settings** in TWRP and uncheck signature verification.